# DAX Measure count transaction based on condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m trying to create dax measure that counts transactions for only ids with one transaction or more in the same table for specific transaction type.
example transactions table (from this table I need to count number of transactions for customers whome having atleast one transaction of type A:

| id | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 2 | B | 5 |
| 2 | C | 11 |
| 3 | A | 4 |
| 3 | C | 1 |

- in this example only id 1 and 3 shoulde be considered.

expected output :

| type | sum(count) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 14 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 1 |

Noting that I need only measures to achieve this since I’m connecting to SSAS model (live connection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible with a very efficient single measure and from the current table without requiring any table modification.

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table 1'[count] ),
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Table 1'[id] ), 'Table 1'[type] IN { "A" } )
)
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 **Custom Column** and 1 **Measure** to achieve your required output as below-

**Custom Columns**-

```
custom_cplumn_count_A = 

var current_row_id = your_table_name[id]
var a_count =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[type] = "A"
            && your_table_name[id] = current_row_id
    )
)

RETURN if(a_count >= 1,1,0)
```

```
custom_column_count_A_2 = your_table_name[count] * your_table_name[custom_cplumn_count_A]
```

**Measure**-

```
sum_count = sum(your_table_name[custom_column_count_A_2])
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I need only measures to achieve this, since I’m having live connection to SSAS model and only allowed to create measures.

Comment: That case, can you add those column in the transformation layer (power query editor)?

Comment: Possible with a single measure